# How to find the expansion in power of x?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

How to find the expansion in power of x of the following function?

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 + x)^2}$$

We are given the hint that $f(x)$ is the derivative of

$$ -\frac{1}{1 + x}$$

I also know that the expansion should follow some form of

$$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +\ldots + x^k + \ldots$$
However I am not sure where to begin in finding the expansion

Comment: Where is the expansion expanded at?

Comment: x? I think its just the general form

Comment: The answer is supposed to be 1 - 2x + 3x^2 - 4x^3 + 5x^4... I just don't know HOW to get here or what the general form of x^k to continue the expansion should be

Comment: Do you know the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x}$? From that expansion, you can try to square it when there are $2$, $3$ or $4$ terms, and use induction to prove the pattern you see.

Comment: No I don't know the expansion of 1/(1+x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(x) &= - \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{1+x}\right)\\
&= - \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-x)^i \text{, by Geometric sum}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}\frac{d}{dx} x^i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}ix^{i-1} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^{i}(i+1)x^i
\end{align}

Remark: Actually we should still justify when can we perform termwise differentiation.